# Is it necessary to create a parse tree from CFG (Context Free grammar) that does not contain left recursive?

Tags: computer-science

Is it necessary to create a parse tree from CFG (Context Free grammar) that does not contain left recursive ? If yes, why? If not then when is the need to use CFG which does not contain left recursive?
example input aacba

Comment: What do you mean by "necessary"? For who/what should a parse tree be "necessary"?

Comment: means like is to get the best results in making a parse tree from cfg